# Simple Family Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a simple database with these tables:

**Table 1 (People Table)**

```
Person_ID INT,
Person_name TEXT,
Person_age INT,
Person_birthdate DATE
```

**Table 2 (Parent & Child Table)**

```
Parent_ID INT,
Child_ID INT
```

In the first table all the people of my family are entered with basic information, in the second table each parent is entered with their child.

For example: my mom has ID #77 and my dad had ID #42 and I have ID #53. The rows in the second table would be:

```
Parent ID | Child ID
77        | 53
42        | 53
```

My question is how do I print all the children in the last generation from a person id?

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: @Siyual SQL Server

Comment: There seem to be a flaw in your design. In this design, a preson can have more than 2 parents...

Comment: Also, never use te TEXT data type, unless you are working on version 2000 or less, and for very large strings. for a person name varchar(50) is more than enough.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a recursive common table expression (cte) to get all descendants, joins to the `Person` table for details, and filters people who have their own children out with `not exists()`.

test setup: http://rextester.com/QTTIS9257

```
create table Person (
    Person_Id int
  , Person_Name varchar(32)
  , Person_Age int
  , Person_BirthDate date
);
insert into Person (Person_Id, Person_Name) values
(53,'Bader');

create table ParentChild (
    Child_Id int not null
  , Parent_Id int null
);
insert into ParentChild values
(53,42),(53,77),(42,21),(77,9),(9,null),(21,null);
```

---

```
declare @PersonId int;
set @PersonId = 9; -- Parent to 77

/* recursive cte to get all descendantsof @PersonId*/
with cte as (
select Parent_Id, Child_Id
  from ParentChild
  where Parent_Id = @PersonId 
union all
select c.Parent_Id, c.Child_Id
from ParentChild c
  inner join cte p
  on c.Parent_Id = p.Child_Id
)

/* join Person to cte to get Person's details */
select p.* 
    from Person as p
      inner join cte
        on p.Person_Id = cte.Child_Id
/* don't return children who are parents */
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from cte i
  where i.Parent_Id = p.Person_Id
  );
```

results:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------------+
| Person_Id | Person_Name | Person_Age | Person_BirthDate |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------------+
|        53 | Bader       | NULL       | NULL             |
+-----------+-------------+------------+------------------+
```